# Create Resizable and Moveable Object on the Desktrop Screen in Python

Tags: python, graphics, screen

Hey Guys. Hope you are all doing well.

Right now, I need to create a moveable and resizeable circle object with Python. I need to be able to resize the object by dragging my mouse over its corners (just like I would do on Paint), and move it by dragging my mouse on it. And I do not want this circle object to appear on an external app screen/window. Let me show you what I mean by that:

[image]

Above image is what I want. This circle needs to be moveable and resizeable.

I though about using Tkinter, however, I do not have many knowledge on it. I do not know if I would be able to remove the Tkinter app screen, and make the object moveable. Can you help me with that?

Comment: It wouldn't be easy with `tkinter` but certainly doable

Comment: @Cool Cloud, can you show me somewhere which has information on that? I just need to get rid of the external app window and be able to get the coordinates of the object.

Comment: I am not sure, basically `root.attributes('-transparentcolor','black')` and the bg of your window will be black. To make the topbar disappear, `root.overrideredirect(1)`. And then some kind of mechanism to move the circle with mouse drag and resize of circles, basic `tk.Canvas` stuff. Plus this transparent thing is not cross platform, will work on Windows only.